# OS X Lion mysterious user cron job just does echo "PATH is $PATH"

Tags: macos, cron

OS X Lion 10.7.3.

Console view of system.log shows log entries for cron jobs defined in my user crontab as expected. Follow this [link](http://skyprod.net/~mcook/OSX/ECHO.mcook.user.crontab.2012-05-07.txt) to view a copy of my user crontab if you want.

I inspected `/usr/local/cron/tab` as root and the system copy of my crontab is also as expected (the job entries are exactly the same as what I see when I do crontab -e).

Here's my question: every now and again I see a message like this in system.log:

*May  7 02:36:17 echo mcook[70156]: mcook cron job PATH is /Users/mcook/local/bin:/Users/mcook/local/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/sw/bin:/sw/sbin:/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6/Home/bin:.:/Users/mcook/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/usr/X11/bin*

I am puzzled because I can't find a matching cron tab entry for this. It's my user name, but none of the cron jobs I have in my user cron table just says *echo "PATH is $PATH"*. The message appears at odd times, but I can't see an obvious pattern: yesterday at 04:23:59, today at 02:36:17 and 02:47:22

Where else can I look to find out where this is coming from? Could the cause be some old data hanging around in some `.plist` somewhere?

My crontab says "The periodic and atrun jobs have moved to launchd jobs see /System/Library/LaunchDaemons". I checked those and the files in `/etc/periodic` but I still did not find a possible cause.

Does someone have other suggestions as to where this might come from?

Answer (score -1):

`launchd` holds files in `~/Library/LaunchAgents` for individual users.

Comment: I only have these in ~/Library/LaunchAgents:

com.adobe.ARM.*.plist*
com.apple.AddressBook.ScheduledSync.PHXCardDAVSource.*.plist (two)
org.virtualbox.vboxwebsrv.plist*

Comment: I found the answer to my own silly question.

Found the following redundant statement in my own shell script nsu-syslog (part of my weird and wonderful [nsu][1] utility that I run from X nearly every time I start it):

`logger mcook cron job PATH is $PATH`

At one time I tried running that script as a cron job (see the last job, commented out, in my user crontab listing). You can't start an xterm from a cron job, of course. 

I'm not advertising, honest. Just having a senior moment.
      


  [1]: http://sourceforge.net/projects/nsu

Comment: You should add that as an answer